# Convergence of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i$

Tags: probability, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

Assume that $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $EX_i=0$ and $VX_i = \sigma^2 < \infty$.

What are the conditions on a sequence of real numbers $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ that allows for the following convergence:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i X_i\rightarrow 0,\;\text{in probability}.$$

Comment: Hint: a sufficient condition would be $L^p$ convergence for any $p \ge 1$. (Now that you have greatly relaxed the assumptions this might not be quite as helpful as before, but it ought to be useful.)

Comment: @whuber Thx for your comment. I just realized that the WLL proof based on the Chebyshev's inequality gives a condition that is useful to me.